# enabling button after complete scroll of iframe in angular js

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to enable button on main page once an iframe is scrolled completely. which confirms that user has seen the complete content of Iframe.
Hence I am trying to attach an scroll event to iframe and once scrollTop reached the height of iframe, I want to set some variable as true `$scope.scrolled = true;` which will enable the "I Agree"  and "I Decline". below is my directive:

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
        var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('iframe').bind('load', function (event) {
          event.target.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,400);
          alert(event.target);
          if(event.target.contentWindow.scrollTop >= 550){
             $scope.scrolled = true;
          }
        });
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      template: '<iframe class="frame" height="550" width="100%" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="{{tncURL}}"></iframe><div class="panel-footer button-bar"><button id="accept" ng-click="acceptTnc(user)" class="btn btn-success inline" ng-disabled="!{{scrolled}}">I Agree</button><button id="decline" ng-click="declineTnc()" class="btn btn-warning inline" ng-disabled="!{{scrolled}}">I Decline</button></div>'
    };
  });
```

Unfortunately I am not able to bind the scroll event to iframe, Is there any way around for this?

plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/IJBWRNwPp6V7Xi6A1i0H?p=preview

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you see the attached Plunker link currently I accept and decline button is disabled. Once user scroll the iframe completely it should be enabled @ComputerDruid